# How can I avoid Guice boiler-plate code

Tags: playframework, guice

How do I avoid guice boiler plate?

With Spring, I usually use @AutoWired and thats it, no createInjector, no injectMemebers(this). Is there a way to avoid those while using giuce? Is there some global settings that I can do so I'll automatically have all things injected in app and test classes?

```
public class AccountDaoTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {  
        Injector injector;
        injector = Guice.createInjector();// I don't want this boiler-plate
        injector.injectMembers(this);
    }

    @Inject
    AccountDAO accountDao ;


    @Test
    public void persist(){
        Account ac =  new Account();
        ac.setName("AccountName");
        ac.setAccountType(AccountType.Hospital);
        accountDao.createAccount(ac);

    }
}
```

Comment: Write a base class or JUnit `@Rule` that doest this for you?

Comment: @Tavian, I'd prefer to avoid "MyTest extends BaseTest". Looking for something on the lines of annotation like _AT_WithGuice on the Test class.

Comment: Well the `@Rule` lets you avoid extending a base class.  There's also Jukito, and @Jan's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for something like the SpringJunitRunner for guice: https://github.com/caarlos0/guice-junit-test-runner

```
@RunWith(GuiceTestRunner.class)
@GuiceModules(MyModule.class)
public class MyTest {
   @Inject
   private Something something;

   @Test
   public void testItWorks() throws Exception {
      Assert.assertThat(something.doSomething(), CoreMatchers.notNullValue());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the example, The code gives RunWith. however we still need to add "custom" boiler-plate-wiring" code in another place :   e.g: bind(Worker.class).to(MyWorker.class);. Curious how we can avoid that "custom" wiring of Worker and MyWorker, and creating MyModules. Ie some way of auto discover and inject.

Answer (score 0):

As Jan suggested, you can cope with manual Injector construction using test runner. For removing the need of having single-use modules with test bindings there's new 'Bound Fields' feature starting from Guice 4 (see the [wiki page](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BoundFields))

Not sure both things can work together out of the box, but it definitely worth trying.